# How can I set rich text properties on a UITableView footer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if ( section == 0 )
  {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"Section_0_text", @"");
  }
  if ( section == 1 )
  {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"Section_1_text","");
  }
  return nil;  
}
```

Can I modify return string text font, color and other few properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `UITableViewDelegate` class, specifically the methods [`tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForFooterInSection:) and [tableView:heightForFooterInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForFooterInSection:). You can return whatever kind of view you'd like, including--but not limited to--a `UILabel` with whatever text properties you want.

Comment: This solution worked. I had to also implement tableView:heightForFooterInSection. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to return your own view with custom text color etc.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon what willi said, keep in mind that this doesn't need to be a complicated custom view or anything. You can return a simple `UILabel` object all styled with your fonts and colors, and that will work fine. In fact, it's how Apple's API docs recommend you accomplish this.

> The table view uses a fixed font style
>   for section footer titles. If you want
>   a different font style, return a
>   custom view (for example, a UILabel
>   object) in the delegate method
>   tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
>   instead.

Comment: First i implemented this, but i am facing a problem with this. I've two section and both the sections have footer and if i implemented using UIlable then footer is not shown as it should be. UILable is drawn on top of my second section, And i don't know how to move second section's Y location.